# How to refactor repeated code

Tags: python, gensim

I have those 2 functions which differs in only 1 line, so to avoid code duplication, I want to create a base class with a general form of those functions then inherit it for each class.

function 1:

```
def top_similar_traces(self, stack_trace, top=10):
        words_to_test = StackTraceProcessor.preprocess(stack_trace)
        words_to_test_clean = [w for w in np.unique(words_to_test).tolist() if w in model]

        # Cos-similarity
        all_distances = np.array(1.0 - np.dot(model.wv.syn0norm, model.wv.syn0norm[
            [model.wv.vocab[word].index for word in words_to_test_clean]].transpose()), dtype=np.double)

        for i, (doc_id, rwmd_distance) in enumerate(distances):

            doc_words_clean = [w for w in self.corpus[doc_id] if w in model]
            wmd = self.wmdistance(model, words_to_test_clean, doc_words_clean, all_distances)

        return sorted(similarities, key=lambda v: v[1])[:top]
```

function 2:

```
def top_similar_traces(self, stack_trace, top=10):
        words_to_test = StackTraceProcessor.preprocess(stack_trace)
        words_to_test_clean = [w for w in np.unique(words_to_test).tolist() if w in model]

        # Cos-similarity
        all_distances = np.array(1.0 - np.dot(model.wv.syn0norm, model.wv.syn0norm[
            [model.wv.vocab[word].index for word in words_to_test_clean]].transpose()), dtype=np.double)

        for i, (doc_id, rwmd_distance) in enumerate(distances):

            doc_words_clean = [w for w in self.corpus[doc_id].words if w in model]
            wmd = self.wmdistance(model, words_to_test_clean, doc_words_clean, all_distances)

        return sorted(similarities, key=lambda v: v[1])[:top]
```

You can see the only difference is at

```
        doc_words_clean = [w for w in self.corpus[doc_id].words if w in model]
        doc_words_clean = [w for w in self.corpus[doc_id] if w in model]
```

Comment: Please do _not_ include links to external sites, but post all _relevant_ code as a part of your question.

Comment: SLIGHTLY ugly solution: You could make two functions that generates the list and pass them in the function argument. They must of course take ``self.corpus[doc_id]`` as input and return the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply extract the changing part into a separate method. That way, bases classes can just overwrite that part and affect the original method without having to duplicate the whole code.

Something like this:

```
# Base class
def top_similar_traces(self, stack_trace, top=10):
    words_to_test = StackTraceProcessor.preprocess(stack_trace)
    words_to_test_clean = [w for w in np.unique(words_to_test).tolist() if w in model]

    # Cos-similarity
    all_distances = np.array(1.0 - np.dot(model.wv.syn0norm, model.wv.syn0norm[
        [model.wv.vocab[word].index for word in words_to_test_clean]].transpose()), dtype=np.double)

    for i, (doc_id, rwmd_distance) in enumerate(distances):
        # call another method here
        doc_words_clean = self.top_similar_traces_filter_words(doc_id)
        wmd = self.wmdistance(model, words_to_test_clean, doc_words_clean, all_distances)

    return sorted(similarities, key=lambda v: v[1])[:top]

# Subclass A
def top_similar_traces_filter_words(self, doc_id):
    return [w for w in self.corpus[doc_id].words if w in model]

# Subclass B
def top_similar_traces_filter_words(self, doc_id):
    return [w for w in self.corpus[doc_id] if w in model]
```

Btw. I don’t know where your `model` comes from, but it appears to be a global variable. You should probably avoid that and put it inside your class instead (or pass it in).

Answer (score 1):

You could define the function in the super class like:

```
def top_similar_traces(self, stack_trace, t, top=10):
    words_to_test = StackTraceProcessor.preprocess(stack_trace)
    words_to_test_clean = [w for w in np.unique(words_to_test).tolist() if w in model]

    # Cos-similarity
    all_distances = np.array(1.0 - np.dot(model.wv.syn0norm, model.wv.syn0norm[
        [model.wv.vocab[word].index for word in words_to_test_clean]].transpose()), dtype=np.double)

    for i, (doc_id, rwmd_distance) in enumerate(distances):

        if t=="something":
            doc_words_clean = [w for w in self.corpus[doc_id] if w in model]
        else:
            doc_words_clean = [w for w in self.corpus[doc_id].words if w in model]
        wmd = self.wmdistance(model, words_to_test_clean, doc_words_clean, all_distances)

    return sorted(similarities, key=lambda v: v[1])[:top]
```

Where `t` is a string which makes the decision you want, and then you should call this method from your subclasses like:

```
def top_similar_traces(self, stack_trace, top=10):
    return super().top_similar_traces(stack_trace, "option", top)
```

A solution like this should work. `t` could be any type of variable (integer, string, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You mention "...I want to create a base class with a general form of those functions then inherit it for each class."

I would like to point out that it is not necessary to create a Class for this. Using a single function will work just fine. In the following example, I added a fourth argument called `words` and set the value to `True`. If you leave it as `True`, the function uses the line where you examine `self.corpus[doc_id].words`. If you call the function using `False`, it will use the line where you examine `self.corpus[doc_id]`.

```
def top_similar_traces(self, stack_trace, top=10, words=True):
    words_to_test = StackTraceProcessor.preprocess(stack_trace)
    words_to_test_clean = [w for w in np.unique(words_to_test).tolist() if w in model]

    # Cos-similarity
    all_distances = np.array(1.0 - np.dot(model.wv.syn0norm, model.wv.syn0norm[[model.wv.vocab[word].index for word in words_to_test_clean]].transpose()), dtype=np.double)

    for i, (doc_id, rwmd_distance) in enumerate(distances):
        if words == True:
            doc_words_clean = [w for w in self.corpus[doc_id].words if w in model]
        else:
            doc_words_clean = [w for w in self.corpus[doc_id] if w in model]
        wmd = self.wmdistance(model, words_to_test_clean, doc_words_clean, all_distances)

     return sorted(similarities, key=lambda v: v[1])[:top]
```

To use the function to examine self.corpus[doc_id].words, call it this way:

```
top_similar_traces(<stack_trace>)
```

To use the function to examine self.corpus[doc_id], call it this way:

```
top_similar_traces(<stack_trace>, words=False)
```